# Validating Email Addresses With a Filter : hackerrnak problem

Tags: python, regex

I want a regular expression way to solve this problem.

I have solved the problem in Hackerrank [Validating Email Addresses With a Filter](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/validate-list-of-email-address-with-filter/problem)

Here is my solution :

```
def fun(s):
    if s.count('@')==1 and s.count('.')==1:
        username, websites = s.split('@')
        website, extension = websites.split('.')
        if  not (len(username)>0 and len(website)>0 and website.isalnum() and len(extension)<=3):
            return False        
        for i in username:
            if  not (i.isalpha() or i.isdigit() or i in ['-','_']):
                return False         
        return True
    return False
```

I find it can be done using regex.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: regex  solution for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be noted that using a regex to match *generic* mail addresses can be very difficult and not as trivial as it may seem.

However, the rules of this challenge simplify this a lot:

> - It must have the `username@websitename.extension` format type.
> - The username can only contain letters, digits, dashes and underscores.
> - The website name can only have letters and digits.
> - The maximum length of the extension is 3.

An example regex would be `^[\w-]+@[a-zA-Z\d]+\..{,3}$`

Comment: I believe that wouldn't work in this specific context, since it would match even a string with an extension more than 3 letters (e.g. `'many@letter.extension'`)

Comment: @gmds Fixed that using line anchors

Comment: @DeepSpace both expersions works 
`^[A-z0-9_-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.\w{,3}$` , `^[\w-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\..{,3}$`  can you please explain differnece here using `^[A-z0-9_-]+` and `^[\w-]+` . thanks

Comment: @prashantrana `\w` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Comment: @Toto point taken, but this question is tagged with `python` and it works with the built-in `re` module

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
def fun(s):
    emailed=[]
    if bool(re.match(r'^([a-z0-9_\-]+)@([a-z0-9]+)\.([a-z]{1,3})$',s)):
        emailed.append(s)
    elif s=='': 
        return []
    


    return sorted(emailed)             
        

def filter_mail(emails):
    return list(filter(fun, emails))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    emails = []
    for _ in range(n):
        emails.append(input())

filtered_emails = filter_mail(emails)
filtered_emails.sort()
print(filtered_emails)
```

Answer (score 0):

The rules seem a bit weird (the extension can be anything as long as its length is maximum 3?). Nevertheless, `'[\w\d-]+@[A-Za-z\d]\..{1,3}$'` should work.

Note: you need the `$` (which represents the end of the string), or you will *match* any e-mail address with an extension more than 3 letters long, which for the purposes of this question is wrong, I believe.